# Understanding promise chaining with this simple example

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I need the following logic but I can't get it. When user is found (not  `undefined`) I need to compare the password (another promise) which returns a `boolean`). Need to:

- return `undefined` (HTTP 404) when user doesn't exist
- throw `ForbiddenError` (HTTP 403) when password is wrong
- return `user` (HTTP 200) when user exists and password matches

First attempt (ugly, unreadable):

```
  @Post()
  login(
    @BodyParam('username', { required: true }) username: string,
    @BodyParam('password', { required: true }) plainPassword: string,
  ) {

    return this.userRepository.findOne({ username: username, enable: true })
      .then ((user: User | undefined) => {
        if (!user) {
          return undefined; // 404
        }

        return bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, user.password)
          .then(passwordMatch => {
            if (!passwordMatch) {
              throw new ForbiddenError('Authentication failed.'); // 403
            }

            return user; // 200
          });
      });
  }
```

Second attempt doesn't work, always returns `'ok'`:

```
return this.userRepository.findOne({ username: username, enable: true })
  .then((user: User | undefined) => {
    if (!user) {
      return undefined; // 404
    }

    return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  })
  .then(passwordMatch => {
    // Doesn't work: this is executed every time (even if user is undefined).

    return 'ok';
  });
```

Comment: So the first one works? Is it really *so* awful?

Comment: Since you're chaining, on your second snippet, you need to `throw` an Error instead of returning `undefined` to break the promise chain.

Comment: @ionizer Ok i see. If I throw, in the second then (second example), how I get the user variable (for returning it)?

Comment: @JaredSmith it's not that ugly _now_, but I maybe need to add more checks in the future.

Comment: You can always use the `.catch()` block to handle your errors. But why would you use the `undefined` user variable after throwing though?.

Comment: I need the user variable in my last then (that is, user exists and passwordMach is the password check).

Comment: @gremo that's totally fair. I'd use TJ Crowder's second version from his answer.

Comment: Life would be simpler if you could throw 403s and 404s alike.

Answer (score 3):

Your `then` handler at the end is always run (well, if the promises don't reject) because the first promise resolves with `undefined` if the user doesn't exist, or with a boolean if the user does exist.

Your nested version was fine. If you need to return `user` in the successful case, it's probably the way to go.

But if you just need to return `'ok'` as in your second code example in the successful case, you *could* flatten things, you just have to handle the `undefined` you'll get if there's no user. We can also take advantage of the fact that you know `user` will have the value `undefined` if the user wasn't found:

```
return this.userRepository.findOne({ username: username, enable: true })
  // The `then` below returns `undefined` if `user` is `undefined`, the promise from `compare` otherwise
  .then((user: User | undefined) => user && bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))
  .then(passwordMatch => {
    if (passwordMatch === undefined) {
      // No user
      return undefined;
    } else if (!passwordMatch) {
      // Bad password
      throw new ForbiddenError('Authentication failed.'); // 403
    } else {
      // All good
      return 'ok';
    }
  });
```

If you want to flatten it **and** return `user`, then you need to propagate `user` to the next handler:

```
return this.userRepository.findOne({ username: username, enable: true })
  .then((user: User | undefined) => {
    return !user
        ? {user} // will be {undefined}
        : bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
            .then(passwordMatch => ({user, passwordMatch})); // *** Note making an object
  })
  .then(({user, passwordMatch}) => { // *** Note destructuring
    if (user === undefined) {
      // No user
      return undefined;
    } else if (!passwordMatch) {
      // Bad password
      throw new ForbiddenError('Authentication failed.'); // 403
    } else {
      // All good
      return user; // 200
    }
  });
```

*(That first `then` handler could be a concise arrow as in the first code block above, but it started getting ugly.)*

Comment: I may like the idea of returning `undefined` or the result of `compare` in the first `then` (first code sample). But I need to return the user.

Comment: @ionizer: **Thanks!** Actually, it's worse than that -- the destructuring will fail in that case, and I didn't handle it. I've fixed that now, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @gremo: If you need to return `user`, then I'd either stick with your nested handlers, or use the (corrected) final approach in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

When you `return undefined`, that makes the first `then()` callback's promise resolve to `undefined`.

Your second `then()` callback then executes, receiving `undefined` as a parameter.

You should change the second callback to check for that.